# Attaching pdf files to qgis2web webmap accessible through a server

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin, qgis2web

I have made a webmap using QGIS2Web. 
I am able to attach pdf documents using    the line

```
<a target="_blank" href="file:///C:/xxx.pdf">google report</a>
```

When the webmap source files (shown in the image below) are on a local drive,it is possible to access the pdf. However, when i move them to a server, i can't access the pdf files.
[image: webmap source files]

Is it possible to have them in a folder in similar location to that of the source files and if so how do i edit the code to read them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the URL in your link either to an absolute URL like:

```
https://www.yourdomain/com/path/to/files/filenameXXX.pdf
```

Or, if you are putting the PDFs in a subfolder within the webmap folder, use a relative URL like:

```
./pdf/filenameXXX.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) to host you QGIS maps and attachments out of the box (see http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/layers_settings.html#adding-photos-to-geodata). Any files are supported, but only for images now available preview capability.

Documentation is [here](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html).

[image]

Comment: Are you associated with nextgis? If so, please leave a notice indicating you are a developer for the project, otherwise people will assume this is SPAM.

Comment: Yes, I'm developer from [NextGIS](http://nextgis.com/).